# Получение ширины полосы прокрутки

Tags: jquery, javascript

Без использования *jQuery* это будет выглядеть так.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.style.overflowY = 'scroll';
div.style.width =  '50px';
div.style.height = '50px';
div.style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.body.appendChild(div);
var scrollWidth = div.offsetWidth - div.clientWidth;
document.body.removeChild(div);
alert( scrollWidth );
```

С *jQuery* не знаю:

```
var div = $("<div>").css({
    "overflowY": "scroll",
    "width": "50px",
    "height": "50px",
    "visibility": "hidden"
}).appendTo("body");
var scrollWidth = div.offsetWidth - div.width(); //NaN, т.к нет offsetWidth 
div.remove();
alert(scrollWidth);
```

Comment: http://cropme.ru/124a4d10b49c4c2cfe6aa6804bdc818e

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Посмотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/YY9k6/)**

```
function scrollbarWidth() {
    var block = $('<div>').css({'height':'50px','width':'50px'}),
        indicator = $('<div>').css({'height':'200px'});

    $('body').append(block.append(indicator));
    var w1 = $('div', block).innerWidth();    
    block.css('overflow-y', 'scroll');
    var w2 = $('div', block).innerWidth();
    $(block).remove();
    return (w1 - w2);
}

alert(scrollbarWidth());
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно проще поступить - из ширины окна вычитаем ширину контента:

```
function scrollbarWidth() {
  var documentWidth = parseInt(document.documentElement.clientWidth);
  var windowsWidth = parseInt(window.innerWidth);
  var scrollbarWidth = windowsWidth - documentWidth;
  return scrollbarWidth;
}
```

Это полезно использовать при сочетании css и js для формирования документа. Стили используют ширину окна, если используется медиа запрос

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px)
```

И для соответствия точек перехода надо это учитывать.

Answer (score 0):

Для выяснения, например, вертикального скроллинга нужно сравнить `offsetWidth` с `clientWidth` - с добавлением `(sic!) borderLeftWidth` и `borderRightWidth`.

Пояснения см. [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21064101/understanding-offsetwidth-clientwidth-scrollwidth-and-height-respectively)

Answer (score 0):

> const width = document.documentElement; const mainWidth =
> width.clientWidth; const windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
> console.log(windowWidth - mainWidth);

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]